# how to GET 2 observations of 2 different codes of one patient in one request from FHIR server?

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

i tried this
https://fhirtest.uhn.ca/baseDstu3/Observation?code=3141-9&code=20570-8&_count=1&patient=653528&_format=json&_pretty=true

but it returned

{
  "resourceType": "Bundle",
  "id": "dcd5cd91-de96-4a3e-a0c9-0cbfccf584e1",
  "meta": {
    "lastUpdated": "2018-01-13T06:10:21.398-05:00"
  },
  "type": "searchset",
  "total": 0,
  "link": [
    {
      "relation": "self",
      "url": "https://fhirtest.uhn.ca/baseDstu3/Observation?_format=json&_pretty=true&code=3141-9&code=20570-8"
    }
  ]
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're performing an 'AND' search by using the '&'. In this case, you will want to search Observations with code x OR code y. You can do this with a ',':

https://fhirtest.uhn.ca/baseDstu3/Observation?code=3141-9,20570-8&_count=1&patient=653528&_format=json&_pretty=true

should give you the result you were looking for.